# Content Security Policy style-src refuses to load in Safari

Tags: safari, http-headers, content-security-policy

Using Safari 11.0 I am receiving an error trying to load a CSS resource on a website I maintain. The page loads fine in Chrome and Firefox, and used to load fine in Safari, so I'm not sure how to resolve it. I'm guessing I need to modify the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

The specific error from the Safari console is `Refused to load https://****.com/css/styles.css because it does not appear in the style-src directive of the Content Security Policy.` As a result of this, the `styles.css` file isn't loading and the website is rendered incorrectly.

The security headers for the website (set via caddy) are:

`Content-Security-Policy    default-src 'self' https:; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Referrer-Policy strict-origin
Server  Caddy
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `style-src` part of the `Content-Security-Policy` header value so that it’s instead `style-src 'self' https://****.com`. That is, replace the `****.com` in `https://****.com` with whatever the actual hostname is.